# Correct implementation of the equals()-Method for fractions

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, fractions

I want that the printn methods give me "Asterix" and "Oberlix" since 3/4 is the same as 6/8.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put(new Fraction(3, 4), "Asterix");
hm.put(new Fraction(19, 12), "Oberlix");
System.out.println(hm.get(new Fraction(6, 8)));
System.out.println(hm.get(new Fraction(38, 24)));
```

So that is how I implemented the equals-Method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean isEqual = false;

    if(obj instanceof Fraction) {
        Fraction frac = (Fraction) obj;

        if(((double) this.numerator / (double) this.denumerator) == ((double) frac.numerator / (double) frac.denumerator)) {
            isEqual = true;
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

Obviously I did something wrong, because that doesn't work and my print method returns "null". My idea was that if I devide the numerator and the denumerator of both fractions, the result must be equal, if the fractions are equal (3/4 is the same as 6/8).

Sorry guys, I guess the mistake must be somehow obvious but I can't find it.

Comment: Firstly, you need to override and implement `hashCode` for hash-based collections. Second I would strongly suggest you use generic parametrization with your `Map`.

Comment: For starters, you can't reliably use equality to compare floating point because of rounding errors.

Comment: Never, never use `==` with floating value...

Comment: @chrylis: You definitely have a point in general, but for a simple fraction calculation like this `==` will work just fine.

Comment: @Mena. How does this effect the HashMap in this case? The first part wasn't written by me, sorry.

Comment: @chrylis I see, do you have any other idea?

Comment: @DennisvonEich Mena has already pinpointed your problem. If you want to put it in a `HashMap` you need to override and implement the `hashCode` function per the contract for `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: @DennisvonEich Have a look at the java source code of the method `hashCode` in `java.lang.Double` (and apply that to `numerator / denominator`). This will suffer from the problems that exist in comparing double values with `==` but you will always have this problem if you use a floating point value as the key in a HashMap.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess I need to cancel my fractions in the hashCode() method. Is that the only option? I don't really want to make a method that has to find the gcd.

Answer (score 2):

You could do for equals

```
return denominator * other.numerator == numerator * other.denominator;
```

But nicer is to make canonical Fraction.
Either in the equals or in the constructor normalize the fraction: 6/8 becoming 3/4.

```
public class Fraction implements Number {
    private final int numerator;
    private final int denominator;

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if (denominator < 0) {
            denominator = -denominator;
            numberator = -numerator;
        }
        int commonFactor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        this.numerator = numerator / commonFactor;
        this.denominator = denominator / commonFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        ...
        Fraction otherFraction = ...
        return denominator == otherFraction.denominator
            && numerator == otherFraction.numerator;
    }

    private static int gcd(int x, int y) {
        x = Math.abs(x);
        y = Math.abs(y);
        ...
        while (x != y) {
            if (x > y) {
                x -= y;
            } else {
                y -= x;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```

What is nicer? You can now make a hashCode:

```
@Override
int hashCode() {
    return denominator * 31 + numerator;
}
```

Floating point is an approximating sum of a limited number of powers of 2.

Comment: The two involved values must be combined to form an incedental value. Not using a power of 2 mixes things a bit more up. A prime number often is used for multiplication. And for text one often sees 31, because there are 26 ASCII letters probably. But actually it is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

For a `HashMap` to work, you need to implement both `equals` and `hashCode`. I'll provide a partial answer, for `equals` only, because I don't have much time.

To compare two fractions without resorting to `double`s, just do some simple arithmetic. You have two fractions, `a/b` and `c/d`. Assuming the denominators are nonzero:

```
a/b == c/d
  (multiply left and right by b)
a == c/d*b
  (multiply left and right by d)
a*d == c*b
```

So:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (!(obj instanceof Fraction)) {
    return false;
  }
  Fraction other = (Fraction) obj;
  return this.numerator * other.denominator == other.numerator * this.denominator;
}
```

Note that this won't work for very large fractions; they will overflow. Cast to long if you want to deal with these correctly.

---

For implementing `hashCode`, you could simplify the fraction using the Euclidean algorithm, then xor the hash codes of the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You should never compare double with `==` because `System.out.println(0.1+0.1+0.1)` will not always be `0.3` (for me, it output `0.30000000000000004`). Use `equals` or `compare` method from `Double`.

Because you are storing both numerator and denumenator in your class `Fraction`, you should use a *close enough* condition with a custom epsilon in your `equals` method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean isEqual = false;

    if(obj instanceof Fraction) {
        Fraction frac = (Fraction) obj;

        if(Math.abs(((double)this.numerator)/this.denumerator) - ((double)frac.numerator)/frac.denumerator) < .00000001/*epsilon*/) {
            isEqual = true;
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

Also, you will need to override the `hashCode` method in your class `Fraction` in order to use `HashMap`. Since this `equals` implementation only depend on one value (the result of the fraction) you could use the following :

```
public int hashCode()
{

    return 0;//all Fraction return the same hashCode, which make HashMap call equals each time

    //EDIT: the following is WRONG: assuming eps = 0.1, 299/100 is equals to 300/100 but hashCode will be different (2 and 3).

    //return this.numerator/this.denumerator ;//since those are int (I guess),
    //it will truncate the floating part. So you will just check for the integer part.


}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem of putting this value as a key in a HashMap. Try coming up with an implementation of `hashCode` that incorporates an epsilon and I'll upvote.

Comment: This answer is misleading and wrong on a couple of points. Comparing two fractions the way OP shows in the question will always work using `==` (assuming reasonable fractional values).

Comment: @Keppil This is really interesting. Could you explain why it is ok to use `==` in this case ? And what is 'reasonable fractional values'

Comment: The integer values can be stored exactly, so no problem so far. The result of the two divisions may or may not be possible to express exactly as a `double`, but both sides will have the exact same error, so `==` will work just fine.

Comment: That will not work if you compare two fraction with result differing after max precision `double` right ? So as long as you are dealing with denumerator less than 10^16, it will work. Did I get that right?

Comment: By `reasonable fractional values` I mean that you might start to run into trouble comparing when you get close to overflowing. Also, as you say, if the difference is that small you will definitely have problems, but I don't think you can get there with fractions using `int`.

Answer (score 0):

as the posts from above, the way to your solution is the use of "hasCode()" and not equals().

 Here is an option on how you can get the proper hashCode:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Calculating with double is troublesome sometimes, so i use BigDecimal here
        BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(this.numerator).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(this.denumerator), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        // after this, i just return the hashCode i would get, if if my parameter was a simple Double Value:
        return Double.valueOf(value.doubleValue()).hashCode();
    }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Disregarding that you are throwing away the fractional part in your BigDecimal division, which is probably the a very significant portion when the class is called `Fraction`: why would you convert the BigDecimal to a Double object, then get the hashCode of that, when `BigDecimal` already has an implementation of the method `hashCode` that you can just invoke directly?

Comment: BigDecimal doesn't use the same hashCode as Double. new Double(6/8) has the same hashCode as new Double(3/4). so thatfor i just used the Double hashCode().

Comment: seeing the other answers makes the actual problem clear. And yeah i messed up abit, sorry for this.